# New User Experiencing Problems

Tags: 14.10

I'm sure this is a software problem...
Just installed Ubuntu 14.10 and totally new to Linux from windows.
Full installation to HDD and deleted windows altogether. When I load up I get a series of problems, after signing in:

Sometimes I get no further than the blank orange/brown patterned screen,
sometimes it goes to the home page and display a message `"System problem detected"` and asks if I want to report the problem now Sometimes if I click `"report Problem"` it allows me to enter my password, other times the curser moves, but doesn't respond to clicks, neither does keyboard, so game over and restart.

I have also on random, attempts managed to get firefox to load up, and fire up google, which searches once, then locks up. I Have also managed to get libre-office to load up but freezes when I press or click anything.

Sometimes the system goes into bios (Is this what you call grub??)
I have opened Ubuntu web browser, but when the curser turns into a hand or fist, nothing else works aprt from being able to move the curser around.

This is so frustrating as it's taken me days to get this far, and I'm having trouble convincing myself I'm doing the right thing now.

Please go easy with any response, as I'm a bit thick when it comes to IT :-//

Comment: I see you have tagged your question "14.10". As of posting, the 14.04 release is the latest Ubuntu LTS (which means "long term support") and is likely to have the most stable support for drivers and software for your system.

I have never experienced a major problem with LTS releases but occasionally a *.10 release has been "borked".

Answer (score 1):

If this is a new install and no personal files are going to be lost;  I'd suggest re-installing.  But first [check the md5 sum of the .iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) (the down loaded image) .  And make sure your hardware is supported i.e. if it is a 32bit system you can't install 64 bit.

BIOS is (Basic Input/Output System) – firmware on the motherboard and grub (GRand Unified Bootloader) is the boot loader that loads the OS

Comment: Also: I'd say "LTS" labelled versions are a better choice for first time installs. You really do not need to be at the very edge of the newest/latest with Linux, just something that is still updated - hence "LTS"